# What does "-Wall" in "g++ -Wall test.cpp -o test" do?

Tags: c++, g++

-o changes the output filename (I found that using --help)

But I can't find out what `-Wall` does?

Comment: "man gcc" on your console tells you everything about this flag and a simple google search with "gcc -Wall" as well...

Comment: As a general tip, try reading the `man` entries for programs if you want to know what a switch does, or what switches are available. The `man` page of `gcc`can be read on http://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc - you can do a quick search there for the text "-Wall"

Comment: @David Sauter, Google will not find anything with "-wall". It will exclude all "wall" from search.

Comment: @Kirill Not if you use quotes, like I'm guessing David mean

Comment: See the quotes in my comment? :)

Comment: It is not clear that quotes should be placed in search string :)
Anyway "man gcc" is a great advice.

Comment: You don't need the quotes. Just google `gcc wall`, leaving out the minus sign.

Comment: // , I always thought it was an homage to Larry Wall.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

It's short for "warn all" -- it turns on (almost) all the warnings that g++ can tell you about. Typically a good idea, especially if you're a beginner, because understanding and fixing those warnings can help you fix lots of different kinds of problems in your code.

Comment: More warnings (some of which are pretty useful) can be turned on with `-Wextra` and `-pedantic`.

Comment: It's not (almost) all. It's actually only a very small fraction of the available warnings. It's the ones that "all" agree upon. The *really* good idea is to do `-Wall -Wextra`, and then peruse the manual to find as many *more* warnings you could enable as possible, because even `-Wextra` is only a small subset...

Comment: @DevSolar very good point. Do you know if there's a flag that means "literally *all* the warnings"?

Comment: @MatrixFrog: Unfortunately, there is no such option, at least not for the compilers I know of. And the list of available warnings changes over time... if the GCC team hadn't disabled `-Wunreachable-code` some time back, Apple would be *much* happier these days. ;-)

Answer (score 49):

See man gcc.

**-Wall** turns on these warnings:

```
-Waddress -Warray-bounds (only with -O2) -Wc++0x-compat -Wchar-subscripts
-Wenum-compare (in C/Objc; this is on by default in C++) -Wimplicit-int (C and
 Objective-C only) -Wimplicit-function-declaration (C and Objective-C only) 
-Wcomment -Wformat -Wmain (only for C/ObjC and unless -ffreestanding) 
-Wmissing-braces -Wnonnull -Wparentheses -Wpointer-sign -Wreorder -Wreturn-type 
-Wsequence-point -Wsign-compare (only in C++) -Wstrict-aliasing 
-Wstrict-overflow=1 -Wswitch -Wtrigraphs -Wuninitialized -Wunknown-pragmas 
-Wunused-function -Wunused-label -Wunused-value -Wunused-variable 
-Wvolatile-register-var
```

**-Wextra** contains:

```
-Wclobbered -Wempty-body -Wignored-qualifiers -Wmissing-field-initializers
-Wmissing-parameter-type (C only) -Wold-style-declaration (C only) -Woverride-init
-Wsign-compare -Wtype-limits -Wuninitialized -Wunused-parameter (only with -Wunused
 or -Wall) -Wunused-but-set-parameter (only with -Wunused or -Wall)
```

There are many more warnings which you have to turn on explicitly.

E.g. for our C code we use:

-Wall -Wextra -Waggregate-return -Wcast-align -Wcast-qual -Wdisabled-optimization -Wdiv-by-zero -Wendif-labels -Wformat-extra-args -Wformat-nonliteral -Wformat-security -Wformat-y2k -Wimplicit -Wimport -Winit-self -Winline -Winvalid-pch -Wjump-misses-init -Wlogical-op -Werror=missing-braces -Wmissing-declarations -Wno-missing-format-attribute -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wmultichar -Wpacked -Wpointer-arith -Wreturn-type -Wsequence-point -Wsign-compare -Wstrict-aliasing -Wstrict-aliasing=2 -Wswitch -Wswitch-default -Werror=undef -Wno-unused -Wvariadic-macros -Wwrite-strings -Wc++-compat -Werror=declaration-after-statement -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Wmissing-prototypes -Werror=nested-externs -Werror=old-style-definition -Werror=strict-prototypes

or just the set of warnings with https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_compiler_flags.html, [src](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=autoconf-archive.git;a=blob_plain;f=m4/ax_compiler_flags_cflags.m4)

Comment: FWIW an even more authoritative source is (duh) the [source code](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/c-family/c.opt). You can see what gets pulled in by searching for `LangEnabledBy` or `EnabledBy`.

Answer (score 25):

Sadly enough none of the answers is quoting the actually relevant part of manual, which really brings it to a point:

> This enables all the warnings about constructions that some users consider
>   questionable, and that are easy to avoid (or modify to prevent the warning),
>   even in conjunction with macros.
>
> [...]
>
> Note that some warning flags are not implied by `-Wall`. Some of them warn
>   about constructions that users generally do not consider questionable, but which
>   occasionally you might wish to check for; others warn about constructions that
>   are necessary or hard to avoid in some cases, and there is no simple way to
>   modify the code to suppress the warning. Some of them are enabled by `-Wextra`
>   but many of them must be enabled individually.

Ergo:

- `-Wall` does **not** mean "all warnings".
- It does also **not** mean "(almost) all", not by a long shot.
- It *does* mean a set of individual options *that is bound to change*.

Bottom line, it is about the absolute minimum of warnings you should set. While `-Wall -Wextra` is better, it's still not making use of all the error checking your compiler can do for you.

---

Personally I wouldn't go for less than `-Wall -Wextra -Wfloat-equal -Wundef -Wcast-align -Wwrite-strings -Wlogical-op -Wmissing-declarations -Wredundant-decls -Wshadow -Woverloaded-virtual`. All my current projects actually use a list of warnings longer than that (without triggering any of them). And I do check the manual on every major release for new options. The compiler is your friend. Use whatever diagnostics it can offer you.

Comment: I have started to learn programming using C++. I am using **programming principles and practice using cpp**. My system is ubuntu 16.04, I use vscode as my editor. Do you recommend me to use your `-Wall -Wextra -Wfloat-equal -Wundef -Wcast-align -Wwrite-strings -Wlogical-op -Wmissing-declarations -Wredundant-decls -Wshadow -Woverloaded-virtual` while I compile with `g++ -std=c++11` while I learn c++ and programming? Or should I skip this part and start using error messages flags later on? If so when should I start with the error messages?

Comment: @vkv: I believe that the compiler is really your friend, and you should take advantage of every little bit of good advice it can give you.

Answer (score 6):

It enables warnings which are deemed useful *and* easy to avoid at the source by gcc writers.  There is also -W (-Wextra in newer releases) which are deemed useful but for which work-arounding false positives can be difficult or result in clumsy code.

gcc has also a bunch of other warnings, generally less useful. See http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.3/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options

Answer (score 2):

It `enables most warning messages`.

You can find out more if you use `g++ --help=warnings`.

Answer (score 0):

It enables all warnings. (reads as "Warning All")

Comment: There are actually a lot of warnings it doesn't enable (such as nonvirtual dtor in a class with virtual methods).

Comment: see Yuval's answer: `-Wall` just means "most warnings" instead of "all warnings".

Answer (score -1):

It shows all warnings. I'd recommend also use `-pedantic` to warn about some non-conformant parts of code.

Comment: For gcc doc: "Some users try to use -pedantic to check programs for strict ISO C conformance. They soon find that it does not do quite what they want: it finds some non-ISO practices, but not all—only those for which ISO C requires a diagnostic, and some others for which diagnostics have been added."

Comment: It doesn't give 100% guarantee, but it helps.

Comment: If you hadn't written *some* instead of *all* in "to warn about *all* non-conformant parts", I wouldn't have commented.  But your current formulation just spread the misconception the gcc documentation warn against.

Comment: Fixed. But in practice it is rather looks like a "most of" and not "some".

Comment: `gcc` should deprecate that flag's name and use a different flag if it doesn't imply `all` warnings.