# How would I go about searching this file containing an array for any ships left?

Tags: c++, arrays

The point of this project is to create a battle ship game where the board comes from a file and put into a 2D array. On the board '~' is water and '#' is a ship. Then it asks for coordinates and determines if there is a ship there or not. If there is a ship, it changes the '#' to 'H'. After all of the ships have been destroyed, I have to search for any remaining ships. This is what I have.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <fstream>

using namespace std;

char GameBoard[25][25];

void Fire(int, int);
void FleetSunk(char GameBoard,int& fleet);
int main()
{
    int i;
    int j;
    int row;
    int column;
    int fleet=0;
    ifstream inData;
    inData.open("GameBoard.txt");
    //Program logic
    cout << "Welcome to Battle Ship!" << endl << "Try to sink all of the ships!" << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 25; j++) {
             inData >> GameBoard[i][j];
        }
    }
    do {
        cout << "Please enter a row number 0-24 that you want to hit: ";
        cin >> row;
        cout << "Please enter a column number 0-24 that you want to hit: ";
        cin >> column;
        Fire(row, column);
        FleetSunk(GameBoard[25][25], fleet);
    } while (fleet = 1);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void Fire(int row, int column){
    switch (GameBoard[row][column]) {
    case '#':
        GameBoard[row][column] = 'H';
        cout << "HIT"<<endl;
        break;
    case 'H':
        cout << "HIT AGAIN" << endl;
        break;
    case '~':
        cout << "MISS" << endl;
        break;
    }
}

void FleetSunk(char GameBoard, int& fleet)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 25; j++) {
            if (GameBoard[i][j] == '#') {
                fleet = 1;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "The Fleet has been destroyed!" << endl;
    fleet = 0;
}
```

This is my input file.

```
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~####~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~~~~~~#~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~~~~~~#~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~~~~~~#~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~~~~~~#~~~~~~~~~~~
####~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~####~~~
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~~~~~#~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~~~~~#~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~~~~~#~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~~~~~#~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I think my problem is in the FleetSunk() function, but I do not know how to fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Post an example of a line from your input file.

Comment: GameBoard should be a char** GameBoard

Comment: your usage of Gameboard is a bit problematic. You define it as a global array on the stack. Then you pass just one character to FleetSunk. I would just remove that argument to FleetSunk.

Comment: Replace `fleet = 1` with `fleet == 1` in the loop condition and it should work.

Comment: Also, next time use [`-Wall`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408038/what-does-wall-in-g-wall-test-cpp-o-test-do) before StackOverflow, please (works at least in GCC).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Man that was messy and the description of the problem wasn't very clear.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

const int l = 25;    //just to be easier to debug and change

char GameBoard[l][l];

void Fire(int row, int column){
    switch (GameBoard[row][column]) {
    case '#':
        GameBoard[row][column] = 'H';
        cout << "HIT"<<endl;
        break;
    case 'H':
        cout << "HIT AGAIN" << endl;
        break;
    case '~':
        cout << "MISS" << endl;
        break;
    }
}

int FleetSunk(char GameBoard[][l]){    //you have to pass a char array and not a simple char
    for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < l; j++)
            if (GameBoard[i][j] == '#')
                return 1;    //removed some useless brackets
    cout << "The Fleet has been destroyed!" << endl;
    return 0;
}

int main(){
    int i, j;    //clean a bit
    int row, column;
    int fleet = 0;
    ifstream inData;
    inData.open("GameBoard.txt");
    //Program logic
    cout << "Welcome to Battle Ship!" << endl << "Try to sink all of the ships!" << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < l; j++)
             inData >> GameBoard[i][j];
    do {
        cout << "Please enter a row number 0-" << l-1 << " that you want to hit: ";
        cin >> row;
        cout << "Please enter a column number 0-"<<l-1 << " that you want to hit: ";
        cin >> column;
        Fire(row, column);
        fleet = FleetSunk(GameBoard); //you can assign the value of fleet instead of change his value in the function
    } while (fleet);    //"while fleet is not 0"
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "*i fixed something and watch if it work*" - that seems like one of the worst explanations to the code provided in an answer...

Comment: Yeah, i sould have waited to test if before post it to explain him the changelog, my fault. i'll edit the answer after testing.