# What's the behavior of an uninitialized variable used as its own initializer?

Tags: c++, c, initialization, language-lawyer, selfinitialization

I noticed just now that the following code can be compiled with clang/gcc/clang++/g++, using `c99`, `c11`, `c++11` standards.

```
int main(void) {
    int i = i;
}
```

and even with `-Wall -Wextra`, none of the compilers even reports warnings.

By modifying the code to `int i = i + 1;` and with `-Wall`, they may report:

```
why.c:2:13: warning: variable 'i' is uninitialized when used within its own initialization [-Wuninitialized]
    int i = i + 1;
        ~   ^
1 warning generated.
```

My questions:

- Why is this even allowed by compilers?
- What does the C/C++ standards say about this? Specifically, what's the behavior    of this? UB or implementation dependent?

Comment: There is nothing "even" in `-Wall -Wextra`. That's about the bare minimum in warnings. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408038) of mine to an older question about `-Wall`...

Comment: [`-Wall` is enough for me to get a warning for gcc](https://godbolt.org/z/X0qFUA)

Comment: @Kevin no dice with gcc 7. gcc 8 seems to detect the issue

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Maybe godbolt isn't working right, but I can set it back to gcc 4.4 and it still gives me the warning.

Comment: okaY. Anyway it's a compiler limitation or bug if it doesn't detect that, because it can cause issues later.

Comment: @Kevin watch it, you're using a c++ compiler!!

Comment: @SouravGhosh I hadn't noticed that, but this question has the C++ tag as well. Oddly enough with C I only get it with both `-Wall` and `-Winit-self` but the warning is from `-Wuninitialized`

Comment: Duplicate: [Why does the compiler allow initializing a variable with itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16110546/why-does-the-compiler-allow-initializing-a-variable-with-itself). However, the answers there are not very good. So lets leave this open for now and see if something better comes up. Then we can close the linked post instead.

Comment: I improved the title and will mop up some old, bad duplicates, since the answers posted here so far are already better than those posted for the dupe questions.

Comment: The C++ part is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/14935722/5376789

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Because `i` is uninitialized when use to initialize itself, it has an **indeterminate value** at that time.  An indeterminate value can be either an **unspecified value** or a **trap representation**.

*If* your implementation supports padding bits in integer types and *if* the indeterminate value in question happens to be a trap representation, then using it results in **undefined behavior**.

If your implementation does *not* have padding in integers, then the value is simply **unspecified** and there is *no* undefined behavior.

EDIT:

To elaborate further, the behavior can still be undefined if `i` never has its address taken at some point.  This is detailed in section 6.3.2.1p2 of the C11 standard:

> If the  lvalue  designates  an  object  of  automatic  storage 
>   duration  that  could  have  been declared with the register storage
>   class (never had its address taken), and that object is  uninitialized
>   (not  declared  with  an  initializer  and  no  assignment  to  it 
>   has  been performed prior to use), the behavior is undefined.

So if you never take the address of `i`, then you have undefined behavior.  Otherwise, the statements above apply.

Comment: It is perhaps relevant to include that the scope of identifier `i` begins at the end of its declarator, of which the initializer is not part.  Thus `i` is in scope in its own initializer, even though it is not useful to initialize it with itself.

Comment: Also, there's a bit of a wiggly issue around [C11 6.3.2.1/2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p2), though I don't think that makes your analysis incorrect.

Comment: Can you elaborate this, better with reference to the standard?

Comment: @JohnBollinger This answer is essentially correct. The complete story including the 6.3.2.1 special case can be found here: [(Why) is using an uninitialized variable undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40674888/584518)

Comment: Yes, @Lundin, I didn't say otherwise.  My point is that the OP's code almost, but does not quite, fall into the case covered by 6.3.2.1/2, to which the question of trap representations is irrelevant.

Comment: @JohnBollinger  Added further detail on whether `i` had its address taken.

Comment: That's useful, thanks, but what I was more looking at is that 6.3.2.1/2 fails to apply here because `i` has an initializer -- the very initializer whose behavior is in question.  If instead of an initializer there were an assignment `i = i` then the behavior would be unconditionally undefined.  Already upvoted, though.

Comment: @JohnBollinger  That brings up an interesting point.  `i` was "declared with an initializer" and is therefor not uninitialized as per 6.3.2.1p2, but at the same time it *is* uninitialized at the time it is used.  So which one applies?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was getting at.  But I'm prepared to accept a literal, albeit counterintuitive, reading of the standard.  That is, because `i` is declared with an initializer, it is not "uninitialized", as that term is used in context, even in the initializer.  In any case, that doesn't change my advice to any and everyone about code like this: *don't do that!*

Comment: I think you need to read the standard as: initialization follows the same rules as per simple assignment. During simple assignment, the operands are unsequenced, which probably also makes this UB. Although the evaluation of the right operand has to be done before the point where it is stored. And at that point the variable is uninitialized. I really can't come up with a scenario where this wouldn't be one form of UB or another.

Comment: _An indeterminate value can be either an unspecified value or a trap representation._ Even though it is defined this way in the Standard, the C Standard Committee seem to treat indeterminate value as a distinct value different from any other value.

Comment: Note: the question is dual-tagged; this answer only applies to C

Answer (score 11):

This is a warning, it's not related to the standard.

Warnings are heuristic with "optimistic" approach. The warning is issued only when the compiler is *sure* that it's going to be a problem. In cases like this you have better luck with `clang` or newest versions of `gcc` as stated in comments (see another related question of mine: [why am I not getting an "used uninitialized" warning from gcc in this trivial example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46465442/why-am-i-not-getting-an-used-uninitialized-warning-from-gcc-in-this-trivial-ex)).

anyway, in the first case:

```
int i = i;
```

does nothing, since `i==i` already. It is possible that the assignment is completely optimized out as it's useless. With compilers which don't "see" self-initialization as a problem you can do this without a warning:

```
int i = i;
printf("%d\n",i);
```

Whereas this triggers a warning all right:

```
int i;
printf("%d\n",i);
```

Still, it's bad enough not to be warned about this, since from now on `i` is seen as *initialized*.

In the second case:

```
int i = i + 1;
```

A computation between an uninitialized value and `1` must be performed. Undefined behaviour happens there.

Comment: Good answer; however, I am not sure about the "warnings issued, when the compiler is sure that there is going to be a problem". There are many warnings, where this isn't the case, this is highly dependent on the warning types enabled

Comment: The risk with `int i = i + 1` is that UB is UB, period. Also, signed overflow. Also, much scratching of heads when another coder has to make sense of that code at some later point.

Comment: true! I forgot the _sign_. Edited out to make it simple

Comment: As @Ctx says.  For example, I often find myself building third-party code that causes tons of warnings about use of *possibly* uninitialized variables.  Control-flow analysis in those cases normally shows that the programmer included appropriate logic to ensure that the variable is assigned a value before its value is used.  But the compiler is explicitly *un*sure whether there is a problem.

Comment: `-Wparentheses` would be another example.

Comment: The compiler doesn't _have_ to give a diagnostic here, although any half-decent compiler will. With `-Wall -Wextra`, icc gives a warning for `i=i;`, but gcc and clang don't. Not unless we do something like `int i=i+1;`. Apparently there's something called `-Winit-self` that has to be used explicitly.

Comment: @Lundin Depends on the compiler version & platform apparently. gcc 7.3 windows remains silent even with `-Winit-self`.

Comment: `int i = i;` is undefined behaviour; one possible manifestation of which is "does nothing". Your answer seems to imply that it's harmless

Answer (score 4):

I believe you are okay with getting the warning in case of

```
int i = i + 1;
```

as expected, however, you expect the warning to be displayed even in case of

```
int i = i;
```

also.

> *Why is this even allowed by compilers?*

There is nothing inherently wrong with the statement. See the related discussions:

- [Why does the compiler allow initializing a variable with itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16110546/2173917)
- [Why is initialization of a new variable by itself valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28152298/2173917)

for more insight.

> *What does the C/C++ standards say about this? Specifically, what's the behavior of this? UB or implementation dependent?*

This is undefined behavior, as the type `int` can have trap representation and you never have taken the address of the variable in discussion. So, technically, you'll face UB as soon as you try to use the (indeterminate) value stored in variable `i`.

You should turn on your compiler warnings. In `gcc`,

- [compile with `-Winit-self` to get a warning.](https://godbolt.org/z/DaSuJa) in C.
- [For C++,](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wno-all) `-Winit-self` is enabled with `-Wall` already.

Comment: no dice with `-Winit-self` either here, using `gcc` 7.3.1

Comment: you have a new version of gcc. Mine is older. When you say "probable source of undefined behavior (if the value of the variable is used later on)" it's the same as using it uninitialized.