# Why is it allowed to use a variable in its own declaration?

Tags: c++

```
int main(){
    int i = i;
    return i;
}
```

There are similar questions, but no answer. Maybe I've not searched well enough.

Why the standard doesn't prohibit such expressions? What could possibly be the reason? The expression clearly doesn't make any sense.

**Conclusion**:

`int i = (i=1) + 1;` is a valid expression with a defined behavior.
The example of a recursive lambda with the help of `std::function` is also a very valid use.
Thus, such expressions should not be prohibited because it would be unwise to oblige the compiler to do the analysis(though any decent compiler does it)

Comment: What makes you think this is permitted?

Comment: @ggorlen I'm not going to get an error in many compilers

Comment: The compiler doesn't give an error for many UB things, though, right? See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54200564/6243352

Comment: @ggorlen It is allowed per the standard.  Has very few valid use cases though.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yeah, that's what the dupe indicates--good point.

Comment: alright, since `int x = (x=5) + 1;` is an expression with defined behaviour, such expression can't be prohibited.

Comment: One valid use case is a recursive lambda.  For a lambda to be able to call itself the right hand side of the `=` needs to be able to capture left hand side.

Comment: @NathanOliver can you give an example with the lambda that compiles?

Comment: @DanA. See: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ceaba42c9afb7030

Comment: It does need a `std::function` to get it to actually compile.  Otherwise you get a circular reference.