# G++ Compiler bug?

Tags: c++

Here is what my code looks like which is very simple:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class Test
{
public:
   Test()
   {
      printf ("contructor !\n");
   }

   ~Test()
   {
      printf ("destructor !\n");
   }

   Test(const Test& test)
   {
      printf ("copy contructor !\n");
   }
};


int main()
{
    Test xyz(xyz);
    return 0;
}
```

Then I type
g++ a.cpp; ./a.out

It output:
copy contructor !
destructor !

but no contructor output !
I`m confused, is it a bug of compiler ?

[see pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfyr2.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the behavior of an uninitialized variable used as its own initializer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54200465/whats-the-behavior-of-an-uninitialized-variable-used-as-its-own-initializer)

Comment: Why do you expect a default constructor to be called? There's only one instance of `Test` in the code, and it's constructed using the copy constructor, not the default one.

Comment: No, it's not a compiler bug. Always blame your own program before the tooling.

Answer (score 2):

In the line where you create the object `xyz` the address of this object in known even before the object is created. That means that you may take the reference to this (not created yet) object and pass it as a parameter to the constructor of this object itself. From the compiler point of view it is possible. You don't initialize any fields, so you don't observe any fields initialized with junk. Anyway, you get what you deserve.

Is that just a theoretical question or you really have a practical purpose?

Comment: Why is it UB? [`[basic.life]/7]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#7) seems to permit it.

Comment: I agree with @HolyBlackCat. *using the properties of the glvalue that do not depend on its value is well-defined*.

Comment: @RSahu, finally even I agree with both of you.

Comment: But I still don't understand why an object is getting created (constructor called)... ? there should at least be one constructor (either default or copy) right ?

Comment: @marvinIsSacul The constructor is called because an object is being created, right? That object is being copied from something that is not initialized, thus the copy constructor is used.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, normally we won`t do that, I just found a bug related to this kind of "typo", I thought the compiler will compain about it, but actually no.

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov Oh okay. Thank you.