# What does -Wall flag do when I compile it with the program?

Tags: gcc, compilation, compiler-flags, gprof

I am following a tutorial that says how to profile the program using 
gprof and the command given is like this

> gcc -Wall -pg test_gprof.c test_gprof_new.c -o test_gprof

But it doesn'y give any explanation for this flag (-Wall)

Comment: The explanations of GCC's commandline options are in [the GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.3.0/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html#Invoking-GCC).
You can find the part of the manual you need to read for `-Wall` or any other option by looking in the
[Option Summary](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.3.0/gcc/Option-Summary.html#Option-Summary)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "-Wall" in "g++ -Wall test.cpp -o test" do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408038/what-does-wall-in-g-wall-test-cpp-o-test-do)

Answer (score 10):

As the name suggests it tells the compiler to enable all warning messages i.e. unused variables. This would help you to write better and clean code.